# Responsiveness not working in mobile when hosted on site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

using godaddy, I am forwarding `www.mysite.com` to `https://bgrnature.herokuapp.com/` where my app is hosted:  https://bgrnature.herokuapp.com/

When I open it in desktop or laptop it works fine and when I open it in the mobile I don't see it as responsive.

The navbar items should be displayed inside `icon-bars` but rather it is shown with small font. However, when I open the site using http://localhost:4000 in my computer, then it is responsive for mobile as well as laptop

Not sure why this is happening?

Comment: Probably some caching issues - Open it from Incognito/Private/Porn window

Comment: @AlonEitan Still the same issue. I opened it in Incognito and also tried with cleaning cache etc.

Comment: So open developer tools - Maybe some resource are missing (You'll see error 404 on the Network tab)/JS errors. It's almost impossible to answer, because naturally, we don't have access to your localhost env.

Comment: @AlonEitan there is no 404 error. just checked

Comment: Last attempt - Check the content of the resources loaded in the Network tab - Maybe your server serves some CSS/JS that were not found as HTML, which makes it appear as if the resource are loaded when they're actually not (It happened to me before - So that's why i'm suggesting this). If it's not that then i'm out of ideas - Sorry...

Comment: You have **<!--** `<meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` **-->** which means these meta tags are commented out and not active. Remove **<!--** and **-->**.

Comment: @vanburen I just commented it out to see if it is causing the problem.

Comment: @AlonEitan The contents of html, js, css are loaded. No luck :(

Comment: Seems to work as expected since you've now uncommented the meta tags.

Comment: @vanburen Its not working when I open www.bgrnature.com where the app is hosted. Just figured out that its the issue with heroku and godaddy where the whole app is loaded into `iframe` in godaddy

Comment: @vanburen I know I didn't mention about forwarding to godaddy because I didn't expect that would be the actual problem. I thought it is problem in css or something

Comment: @vanburen Still trying to figure out how to fix this